# Responding to IFindReplaceTarget in my getAdapter() Method in my view

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

So I'm trying to implement a Find feature that will appear using Ctrl+F in my application using Eclipse RCP.

I have already created the command, created the handler and set the key binding.

Inside of my handler is the following:

```
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    IWorkbenchPart w = Utilities.getActivePart();

    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("my.package.Messages");
    FindReplaceAction findReplaceAction = new FindReplaceAction(bundle, "find_replace_action_", w);
    findReplaceAction.setActionDefinitionId(IWorkbenchCommandConstants.EDIT_FIND_AND_REPLACE);


    System.out.println("This is when the find menu appears!....Eventually");
    return null;
}
```

I get an error when trying to create my FindReplaceAction which is due to me not knowing what to return in my getAdapter() method called by the FindReplaceAction class

here is my getAdapter() method:

```
public Object getAdapter(Class clazz) {
if(IFindReplaceTarget.class.equals(clazz)){

        return this;
    }
    return super.getAdapter(clazz);

}
```

This would return my Editor which cannot be casted into the type (IFindReplaceActionTarget) so what should I be returning?

Comment: You should return an object that fully implements that Interface.

Comment: You have to write something that implements IFindReplaceTarget and probably also  IFindReplaceTargetExtension, IFindReplaceTargetExtension2, IFindReplaceTargetExtension3. There are various examples in the Eclipse source code.